# spring boot unit tests No value at JSON path

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsonpath, jayway

I want to make tests for create and update APIs in Spring Boot:

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateNewUser() throws Exception, UserAlreadyExistException {

    User user = User.builder()
            .id(10L)
            .firstName("Alin")
            .lastName("Balan")
            .mail("alin@yahoo.com")
            .password("pass")
            .isAdmin(true)
            .role(Roles.PTE)
            .build();

    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/users")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[10].id",is(10)));

    Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).save(Mockito.any());
}
```

But I have this error

> java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[10].id", exception: json can not be null or empty

Comment: Why passing 10 ?

Comment: you. don't want that test fail when value is absent ?

Comment: @Deadpool I validate those fields..I create  that user and I want to verify if that POST it;s ok

Comment: @Alien even if I pass 0,1 etc I have the same result

Comment: Why not so: `jsonPath("$.id", is(10))` ?

Comment: `jsonPath("$.id", is(10))` would indeed be correct - it seems they've misunderstood `jsonpath`. Have a look at a basic guide [here](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath).

Comment: are you sure your api returns an array when creating a user?

Comment: Have you verified that you get the response you are expecting? If not, (temporarily) add `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.log())` or `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())` before the `.andExpect(...)` and double  check the output

Comment: @njzk2 my api returns an empty body

Comment: Can you show the respective Controller-method. Which type is returned, `User` ? Is there an error-case where another (e.g. empty response) is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how no answer has been posted so far despite the many comments, I'll summarize:

If your API endpoint `POST /api/users` *expects and returns* the following JSON:

```json
{
    "id": 10,
    "firstName": "Alin",
    "lastName": "Balan",
    "mail": "alin@yahoo.com",
    "password": "pass",
    "isAdmin": true,
    "role": "PTE"
}
```

then you could query this JSON via `jsonpath` using:

```
$.id
$.firstName
...
$.isAdmin
$.role
```

not `$[10].id`. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath) is a basic guide on `jsonpath`.

This means that your assertion should look like:

```java
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/users")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id",is(10)));
```

Comment: I tried in this way..but same errors. Errors are:


MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

No value at JSON path "$.id"
json can not be null or empty

Comment: What does your response look like? What does your endpoint return?

Comment: from a post you should expect 201, not 200. Something's off with your api

Comment: @njzk2 That depends on their API implementation. `200 OK` is a valid response code on `POST`. The more RESTful approach, as you say, would be to return `201 Created`.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the complete error-message gave similar:
[No value at JSON path "$.name", exception: json can not be null or empty, Using Mockmvc and Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930241/no-value-at-json-path-name-exception-json-can-not-be-null-or-empty-using#46930623)

#### Assumption on expected JSON response

When creating or updating a single user, you would expect a single user **object** as JSON response - not an array (with 10 user elements).

Then your assertion should check on the ID of the single object in JSON response - to be equal to `10`:

```java
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/users")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
   .andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
   .andExpect(
       MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id", is(10))
   )
);
```

#### Explanation

JSON-path is a formal expression to select nodes of a JSON tree (compare to XPath for selecting XML elements).

- JSON-path expression `$` denotes the root node
- JSON-path `$[10]` evaluates to the 11th element  (zero-based index!) of an array (at root).
- JSON-path `$.id` evaluates to the field named `id` of an object (at root)

See also:

- Baeldung: [Introduction to JSON-path](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath)
- [How to use MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725199/how-to-use-mockmvcresultmatchers-jsonpath#42736879)

Comment: Minor note: `$[10]` would return the *11th* element, as `jsonpath` is 0-indexed.

Comment: I tried in this way..but same errors. Errors are: MockHttpServletResponse: Status = 200 Error message = null Headers = [] Content type = null Body = Forwarded URL = null Redirected URL = null Cookies = [] No value at JSON path "$.id" json can not be null or empty

Comment: @EugenGîrlescu Then please add `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())` before `.andExpect` to verify the __actual JSON output__ in console. And please __edit & clarify your question__: Which JSON-response (format) is expected? Can you show the Controller-method and returning class.

Comment: @user991710 Thanks, great note - fixed & explained.